# Modify Email notifcations with SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, email, custom

I am trying to make the default SharePoint notifications for tasks a little better and more suitable for my cause.
But no matter what I change in this pseudo-code-thing, it always returns errors (even if I only add a dot...).

For clarification:
I use the SharePoint Designer 2013. In a workflow I create a new approval -> go to the menu of the approval by clicking on it -> Change the behavior of a single task -> edit email notification within "Task pending" step.

I really don't know why it wouldn't allow me to change a thing as it is possible and not even in the "real" code of a SharePoint.
I hope you can help me with this issue!

I have attached both the current task notification message as well as the editor box for the message.
 [image: editor box][image: Current message]

[image: Error message]

Comment: I have edited the email of tasks recently and all are ok, can you show the error?

Comment: It just says that there is an error but it can't be displayed.

Comment: Shows no code? Sends the screen where you find that there is an error.

Comment: @DiegoHillesheim I have uplaoded the error message.

Comment: Are you using the "Copy" function?

Comment: No. (12 more to go...)

Comment: You try use the default workflow and only add a log?

Comment: Did you try the "check workflow for Errors"-button? And did you install this hotfix for SharePoint Designer 2013? http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2768343

Comment: Yes, the "check.." always returns nothing. I am downloading the hotfix now.

Answer (score 0):

As time is of the essence on this topic, I just deleted everything and now it works. I don't know why it did't work the first time because I did everything exactly the same in my second try. However, it works. Thank you guys for the support!